# Explaining English Wikipedia revisions diff

Tags: diff, wikipedia

I found [those files](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/diffdb/) on the [download page of Wikipedia](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/).
Entries in those files look like this:

```
206430  12  0   'Anarchism' 1031579715  None    True    3810    u'Bobdobbs1723' 11394:1:u'\n* [[Lysander Spooner]]\n* '
```

This is another line from the last dump (Number 15):

```
348524708   26470001    0   'Southeast air corps training center'   1268053721  u'[[WP:AES|\u2190]]Redirected page to [[Category:USAAF Southeast Training Center]]' False   803088  u'Bwmoll3'  0:1:u'#redirect [[Category:USAAF Southeast Training Center]]'
```

Those are tab-separated values with the 6th column being a list of changes committed on a specific Wikipedia page (The name of the page is in column 4).
I didn't find anything on the web about the structure of those logs. Particularly challenging is the format of the change list where multiple changes are documented.
Does anybody here know about the structure of those files?

Comment: Those are for Lucene, created with [RevDiffSearch](https://github.com/whym/RevDiffSearch) (formerly DiffDb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those dumps are from a tool called [RevDiffSearch](https://github.com/whym/RevDiffSearch) (formerly DiffDb), I believe. They are intended to be used with Lucene, and seem to be restructured versions of diffs from [WikiHadoop](https://github.com/whym/wikihadoop).

The structure is:

```
rev_id    page_id    namespace    title    timestamp   comment    minor     user_id    user_text    diff1_position:diff1_action:diff1_content    diff2_position:diff2_action:diff2_content
```

Where (copy-pasted from [here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/WSoR_datasets/revision_diff)):

- `rev_id`: The identifier of the revision being described PRIMARY KEY
- `page_id`: The identifier of the page being revised
- `namespace`: The identifier of the namespace of the page
- `title`: The title of the page being revised
- `timestamp`: The time the revision took place as a Unix epoch timestamp in seconds
- `comment`: The edit summary left by the editor
- `minor`: Minor status of the edit (boolean)
- `user_id`: The identifier of the editor who saved the revision
- `user_text`: The username of the editor who saved the revision
- `diffs` - Tab separated, diff operations. Each diff operation has three parts (separated by colons):

  - `position`: The position in the article text at which the operation took place
  - `action`: Did the operation add or remove some text? ("1" for add, "-1" for remove)
  - `content`: The text operated on. For added text, this is the content to add. For removed text, this is the content that was removed.